# Can function with IronPython dependencies be called from ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, ironpython

I'm working on a simple ASP.NET Core MVC project I would like to call a function from a controller. This function - RunPyScript() - can be found in a .NET framework class library.

```
 public static string RunPyScript(string sentence)
        {
            var options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            options["Frames"] = true;
            options["FullFrames"] = true;
            var py = Python.CreateEngine(options);

            var searchPath = py.GetSearchPaths();
            searchPath.Add(@"C:\IronPython 2.7\Lib");
            searchPath.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib");
            searchPath.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages");
            py.SetSearchPaths(searchPath);

            var scope = py.CreateScope();
            scope.SetVariable("result", "");
            scope.SetVariable("sentence", sentence);
            py.ExecuteFile(path to the py file, scope);
            if (scope.ContainsVariable("result")) return scope.GetVariable("result");
            return "";
        }
```

RunPyScript() with the help of the IronPyhon.Hosting library runs an external python script and returns a string value. When I try to execute it from the MVC project I get the following error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.CodeDom, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

I added System.CodeDom to the depedencies via NuGet but it did not solve the issue.

I created a .NET framework console project and when I call RunPyScript() from there it works properly. Also when I copied RunPyScript() to the MVC project I get the following error on the ScriptScore.GetVariable/Setvariable functions:

> Error CS7069  Reference to type 'ObjectHandle' claims it is defined in
>   'mscorlib', but it could not be found

Based on this I guess IronPython it not so compatible with .Net Core.
Is there any way that I could get around and call RunPyScript() somehow from my MVC app?

Comment: The just released version of IronPython (2.7.8) has support for .NET Core, so it should be usable from ASP.NET Core. See https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2

Answer (score 0):

As commented already, IronPython 2.7.10 has great support for NetCore now.  The "FileNotFoundException" issues should be resolved if you use NuGet to get the latest packages.

**For posterity's sake:**

Since this is regarding web servers (ASP.NET), there are few things to note about portability and scalability:

1. The python standard library can be included by installing (via NuGet) both "IronPython" and "IronPython.StdLib", so using GetSearchPaths() might not be necessary.
2. Since NetCore can run on Linux, it's usually best to avoid hardcoding paths such as "C:\IronPython 2.7\Lib" for portability.  If absolutely needed, try to keep them in configuration files.
3. If this script gets run frequently, it would be best for performance to return a PythonFunction from your script and convert it to a delegate (Action or Func) and cache that for future calls.  That is, if you can mandate such a change.
4. If you can't change the way that the scripts operate (returning a function delegate isn't possible), try to cache the CompiledCode for later execution so you only get the load/compile penalty the first time. If you handle a lot of scripts or they change, you might need to worry about cache expiration and invalidation, but the gains are well worth the effort.

**How to extract a function as a delegate from a python file**

1. Modify the helper function to return a generic type:

```
public class PythonScript
{
    private ScriptEngine _engine;

    public PythonScript()
    {
        _engine = Python.CreateEngine(new Dictionary<string, object>() {
            { "Frames", true },
            { "FullFrames", true }
        });
    }

    public TResult RunFile<TResult>(string filePath, string variableName)
    {
        ScriptSource source = _engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(filePath);
        CompiledCode cc = source.Compile();

        ScriptScope scope = _engine.CreateScope();
        cc.Execute(scope);

        if (!scope.ContainsVariable(variableName))
            throw new MissingFieldException("Python script failed getting variable: " + variableName);

        return scope.GetVariable<TResult>(variableName);
    }
}
```

3. Define a well-known (to your application) function in your python file:

```
def MyPyFunc(a):
    return 42 + a
```

4. Run your script to extract the function as a delegate:

```
var py = new PythonScript();
var func = py.RunFile<Func<int, int>>(filePath, "MyPyFunc");
var result = func(9);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```